# Display a list of a model in a razor view using NancyFx

Tags: c#, .net, razor, nancy

I'm having trouble just displaying a List with NancyFx. The issue seems to be something pretty basic I'm missing or perhaps the framework has changed from the examples?

My Module looks like this:

```
public IndexModule()
{
    Get["/"] = parameters =>
    {
        dynamic d = new BlogPost();
        return View["index", d];
    };
    Post["/"] = paramters =>
    {
        IEnumerable<BlogPost> result = new List<BlogPost>()
        {
           new BlogPost { Id = 3 },
           new BlogPost { Id = 5 }
        };
        return View["index", result];
    };
}
```

My cshtml:

```
{
         @foreach (var item in Model) 
         {
                  <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @item.Id
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                  </tbody>
         }
}
```

Inside the .cshtml I tried each separately, they didn't work:

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<NancyApplication.Objects.BlogPost>
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<NancyApplication.Objects.BlogPost>
```

Oddly I don't get errors! I Just get a blank page with no html generated at all!

Comment: Is your execution going into the `Get` or `Post` part of the `IndexModule`? It could be that you're just passing an empty `BlogPost` to the view.

Comment: When i execute it just show me a blank screen with no erros about BlogPost or any thing

Comment: Yes, but if you're getting there by way of a `GET` then your model doesn't have anything in it to display.

Comment: yes ,true i just display blank table and on click of a button i want to update the table with my list of model.when i comment foreach statment of my cshtml it show up the page with blank table

Comment: The inherits should be a collection... `@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<IEnumerable<NancyApplication.Objects.BlogPost>>`

Comment: I tried above @inherits also it did n't worked

Comment: @praks what I suggested or what you wrote in your question? Your question is wrong.